# https redirect hell (adding www)

Tags: multisite, redirect, https

I migrated my multisite wordpress website (www.example.com) to a subdomain (dev.example.com) to work on some big changes. Of course, I changed *siteurl* and *home* in the DB for all sites.

The problem is whenever I go to https://dev.example.com I get redirected to a non existing https://www.dev.example.com

I can't figure out where this www is coming from (and it is not .htaccess). This is driving me nuts. After hours of google, I finally decided to reach out for help.

Thanks!

Comment: Remember that redirects are cached by the browser. Making changes to things to try to solve a redirect problem without also restarting the browser completely from time to time is an exercise in endless frustration. ;)

Comment: Thanks @Otto, I have done that in the past. Hours wasted because I forgot to clear the browser cache!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone has a similar problem the answer was a lot more complicated than I thought. It turns out that NameCheap (my hosting company) installed a different SSL cert incorrectly. It was causing a redirect to another site, which applied it's .htaccess rules, adding the "www".

Answer (score 1):

Did you check your ISP's setting? E.g. in Dreamhost's control panel you have these 3 options:

Do you want the www in your URL?

- Leave it alone: Both `http://www.domain.com/` and `http://domain.com/` will work.
- Add WWW: Make `http://domain.com/` redirect to `http://www.domain.com/`
- Remove WWW: Make `http://www.domain.com/` redirect to `http://domain.com/`

Comment: Thanks @break68, I use a provider with cPanel. I'll see if there is something there.

Comment: I found a "redirect" option in cPanel. I guess it reads directly from .htaccess, so I don't think that is going to help. I am just not sure where this redirect is coming from. It has to be wordpress since I don't have any redirect in .htaccess that could be doing this.

Comment: @nhadsall don't rush to blame WP. Simple to check – if you disable WP (`die()` in config file for example), does redirect still happen?

Comment: @Rarst, thanks for the tip. You were right: it isn't WP. Not sure what the problem is then. I'll see if there is some strange cPanel config I am missing. Thanks!